# Chartsjs (blazor) BarChart not alinged

Tags: c#, chart.js, blazor

Im not sure im doing something fairly simple wrong. Im getting below plot when using the below code. I was expecting to get the B values in its own column like you would in excel.

**EDIT:** I have added my config in the post also, if there are some properties that im missing

/Thomas

```
BarDataset<double> _barDataSet3 = new BarDataset<double>
    {
        Label = "A",
        BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
        BorderWidth = 0,
        HoverBackgroundColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
        HoverBorderColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
        HoverBorderWidth = 1,
        BorderColor = "#ffffff"
    };


    _barChartConfig.Data.Labels.AddRange(new[] { "A"});
    _barDataSet3.Add(2.6);
    _barChartConfig.Data.Datasets.Add(_barDataSet3);


    BarDataset<double> _barDataSet4 = new BarDataset<double>
    {
        Label = "B",
        BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
        BorderWidth = 0,
        HoverBackgroundColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
        HoverBorderColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
        HoverBorderWidth = 1,
        BorderColor = "#ffffff"
    };


    _barChartConfig.Data.Labels.AddRange(new[] { "B" });
    _barDataSet4.Add(4.5);
    _barChartConfig.Data.Datasets.Add(_barDataSet4);
```

**EDIT**: My config - is there a property that im missing?:

```
_barChartConfig = new BarConfig
    {
        Options = new BarOptions
        {
            Title = new OptionsTitle
            {
                Display = true,
                Text = "Simple Bar Chart"
            },
            Scales = new BarScales
            {
                XAxes = new List<CartesianAxis>
            {
                    new BarCategoryAxis
                    {
                        BarPercentage = 0.5,
                        BarThickness = BarThickness.Flex
                    }
                },
                YAxes = new List<CartesianAxis>
            {
                    new BarLinearCartesianAxis
                    {
                        Ticks = new LinearCartesianTicks
                        {
                            BeginAtZero = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

[image: Blazor Code Example]

Comment: Have you tried removing the `XAxes` part of the `BarScales` config? I geuss this is causing the problem.

Comment: Hey, I'm the maintainer of the library you're using. If you're still facing this issue, I'd suggest trying with the new [2.0 version](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor/releases/tag/v2.0.0) and opening a new issue on https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor if you don't manage to get it working :)